# Meteor Reference Eror:NotebookSchema not defined

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-autoform

I am trying to create one mongodb collection and trying to attach schema for Generating auto forms
I am Using the folowing two addons for the purpose

1. aldeed:autoform
2. aldedd:collection2

**Mycode**

```
Notebooks = new Mongo.Collection("notebooks");

NotebookSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        label:'Notebook Name'
    },
    author:{
        type:String,
        label:'Author'
    }
});
Notebooks.attachSchema(NotebookSchema);
```

The above code is inside the `collections` folder with file name `Notebooks.js`

**My Application Structure Screen shot**
[image]

**My Error Screen Shot**
[image]

If You need more Information regarding anything please feel free to ask.

Comment: Are you using Meteor^1.3?

Comment: @corvid  I am using `meteor@1.1.15` I found this from versions

Answer (score 1):

You can export your collection in 1.3+, like this.

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { SimpleSchema } from 'meteor/aldeed:simple-schema';

export const Notebooks = new Mongo.Collection('notebooks');
export const NotebookSchema = new SimpleSchema({ /** ... */ });
Notebooks.attachSchema(NotebookSchema);

export default Notebooks;
```

Then, you can import it and expose it as a helper.

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import Notebook from '/imports/collections/Notebook';

Template.whatever.helpers({
  collection() {
    return Notebook;
  }
});
```

Finally, use it in your template like:

```
{{>autoForm id="meow" collection=collection}}
```

Comment: I am using the `meteor@1.1.15`